# "\kern0pt" could correct the "\/" before comma or period in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, italic

For easier use of `{\it text}`, we can define a control sequence such as `\def\ital#1{{\it #1\/}}`, which is suggested at the bottom of page 20 of the TeXbook. Since it will add extra space, which is not needed, before the comma or period following, so on page 306 of the TeXbook, Mr. Knuth said `\def\nocorr{\kern0pt}` could deal with this problem.

```
\def\ital#1{{\it #1\/}}
\def\nocorr{\kern0pt}
\ital{hello}, hello\par
\ital{hello\nocorr}, hello
\bye % end the document
```

The output is

[image]

Why can `\kern0pt` adjust the space to `0pt` before the comma? What is `\kern0pt\/` equal to?

Comment: The italic correction refers to the preceding item in the horizontal list. If you put `\/` after an o, then the italic correction for the o is inserted. If you insert it after `\kern0pt` then you get the "italic correction"of that, which is 0.

Comment: Why doesn't this work, `{\it hello{}\/}, hello`? @campa

Answer (score 5):

To TeX, a character just consists of four lengths: width, height, depth and italic correction.

The command `\/` looks back in the current horizontal list of typeset items (not source code characters such as `{}`) and if the last item in the current horizontal list is a character node, with non zero italic correction, it adds a kern with that length.

So `f\/`  adds the italic correction of f in the current font.

`f{}\/` does the same, as `{}` does not contribute anything to a horizontal list.

`f\kern0pt\/`  is the same as `\f\kern0pt` as `\/` will do nothing if the last item in the current list is a kern node.